Issue While Connecting to Frontend with Anchor Backend
Issue Description
I followed all the steps mentioned in the documentation Full Stack Solana development with React and Anchor:
https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/full-stack-solana-development project. Everything worked smoothly until I reached the frontend part.
Problem 1: IDL File
In the documentation, it instructs to create a new folder named anchor in front-end/src and copy over target/types/counter.ts (from the Anchor program) to a new file called idl.ts. The purpose of this step is to use the IDL to create TypeScript objects for interacting with the program.
However, when I opened target/types/counter.ts, I found that it's different from what was expected. It contains additional content, and the line export const IDL: Counter = { ... } is missing.
My counter.ts was like:

```typescript
/**
 * Program IDL in camelCase format in order to be used in JS/TS.
 *
 * Note that this is only a type helper and is not the actual IDL. The original
 * IDL can be found at `target/idl/counter.json`.
 */
export type Counter = {
    "address": "2FcNSYHzEP7gXYZA4YMfiznRVAj7JpZF8Z4fWL7xw9jK",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "counter",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "spec": "0.1.0",
        "description": "Created with Anchor"
    },
    "instructions": [
        {
            "name": "increment",
            "discriminator": [
                11,
                18,
                104,
                9,
                104,
                174,
                59,
                33
            ],
            "accounts": [
                {
                    "name": "counter",
                    "writable": true,
                    "pda": {
                        "seeds": [
                            {
                                "kind": "const",
                                "value": [
                                    99,
                                    111,
                                    117,
                                    110,
                                    116,
                                    101,
                                    114
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "name": "initialize",
            "discriminator": [
                175,
                175,
                109,
                31,
                13,
                152,
                155,
                237
            ],
            "accounts": [
                {
                    "name": "user",
                    "writable": true,
                    "signer": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "counter",
                    "writable": true,
                    "pda": {
                        "seeds": [
                            {
                                "kind": "const",
                                "value": [
                                    99,
                                    111,
                                    117,
                                    110,
                                    116,
                                    101,
                                    114
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "systemProgram",
                    "address": "11111111111111111111111111111111"
                }
            ],
            "args": []
        }
    ],
    "accounts": [
        {
            "name": "counter",
            "discriminator": [
                255,
                176,
                4,
                245,
                188,
                253,
                124,
                25
            ]
        }
    ],
    "types": [
        {
            "name": "counter",
            "type": {
                "kind": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "count",
                        "type": "u64"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "bump",
                        "type": "u8"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
};


Problem 2: Error in setup.js
After adding the setup.js file, which looks like this:
import { IdlAccounts, Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { IDL, Counter } from "./idl";
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";

const programId = new PublicKey("2FcNSYHzEP7gXYZA4YMfiznRVAj7JpZF8Z4fWL7xw9jK");
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

export const program = new Program<Counter>(IDL, programId, {
  connection,
});

export const [mintPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
  [Buffer.from("mint")],
  program.programId,
);

export const [counterPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
  [Buffer.from("counter")],
  program.programId,
);

export type CounterData = IdlAccounts<Counter>["counter"];

I encountered an error at the line export const program = new Program<Counter>(IDL, programId, { connection, });, which says:
Argument of type 'PublicKey' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Provider'.
Property 'connection' is missing in type 'PublicKey' but required in type 'Provider'.

Problem 3: Error in Frontend
Following the subsequent steps and adding <CounterState/> in App.tsx, I encountered an error in the frontend console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size')
    at new AccountClient (@coral-xyz_anchor.js?v=7e705056:10404:39)
    at @coral-xyz_anchor.js?v=7e705056:10369:30
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at AccountFactory.build (@coral-xyz_anchor.js?v=7e705056:10368:70)
    at NamespaceFactory.build (@coral-xyz_anchor.js?v=7e705056:11480:51)
    at new _Program (@coral-xyz_anchor.js?v=7e705056:11560:98)
    at setup.ts:10:24

Steps Taken

Followed all steps mentioned in the documentation and video.
Checked for typos and ensured correct file placements.
Reviewed code for any missing or incorrect configurations.

Additional Information

Operating System: Windows(using WSL)
solana --version; node -v; yarn --version; anchor --version
solana-cli 1.18.9 (src:9a7dd9ca; feat:3469865029, client:SolanaLabs)
v20.8.0
1.22.22
anchor-cli 0.30.0



  [1]: https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/full-stack-solana-development


This question is good, but should be handled as 3 separate issues.

Could you try replacing the last argument with an instance of an anchor provider?
provider initialization might looks something like this on an anchor project
anchor.AnchorProvider.env().wallet as anchor.Wallet;

export const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(
    connection,
    payer, 
    anchor.AnchorProvider.defaultOptions()
);

This is what the class constructor looks like and as you can see there isn't a parameter for the connection

code https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/ts/packages/anchor/src/program/index.ts#L32

This works for me const program = new anchor.Program(idl, provider);
